# Why does delegation help us avoid dependencies?

Tags: ios, dependencies, delegation

On my lecture slides (from UC Berkeley's iOS course), it said that delegations help us avoid dependencies. However, since a dependency is when an object calls the functions of another object, how is this statement true? For example, if we have a `UIViewController` that conforms to `UITableViewDelegate`, isn't the table view technically calling the this delegate's (another object's) functions?

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret that statement to mean that delegations help minimize dependencies.  You're correct that you can not get rid of dependencies required to define an interface, but by delegating to another implementation you don't have to deal with the dependencies of that other implementation. Much.